# Extract and manipulate the string with Regex in apex

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I need help a with building a regex for extracting a particular string and manipulating it. Here's the example

Actual Input:

```
( 12s ) Agent K: Hello Guest, How are you doing today?<br> <br>How Can I help<br>
( 18s ) Guest:   Hello there! Need access to XYZ<br>
( 53s ) Agent K: Granted the access<br>
( 1m 9s ) Guest: Ok thanks, Agent K<br>
```

I want to identify the appearances of "Agent K:", "Guest:" and all timings coming within brackets and manipulate it to

```
<b>Agent K:</b>.12s Hello Guest, How are you doing today?<br> <br>How Can I help<br>
<b>Guest:</b>.18s   Hello there! Need access to XYZ<br>
<b>Agent K:</b>.53s Granted the access<br>
<b>Guest:</b>.1m 9s Ok thanks, Agent K<br>
```

I started writing regex function to identify the appearances of **) Agent K:** and **) Guest:** so that I'm uniquely identifying their places. For that, I'm using below which returns true

```
string htmlValue = '<br>( 15s ) Agent K: Test Message from user';

string s1 = ') Agent K:';

Boolean found = Pattern.compile('(?i)' + Pattern.quote(s1)).matcher(htmlValue).find();
```

But I'm not sure how I can move next to start manipulating it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `String.replaceAll` to do this in one tidy step:

```
String output = input.replaceAll(
  '(?m)^\\s*\\(\\s*(.+?)\\s*\\)\\s*(.+?:)\\s*\\s*(.+)\\s*$',
  '<strong>$2</strong>.$1 $3'
);
```

Here's an example output:

```
String input = '( 12s ) Agent K: Hello Guest, How are you doing today?<br> <br>How Can I help<br>\n( 18s ) Guest:   Hello there! Need access to XYZ<br>\n( 53s ) Agent K: Granted the access<br>\n( 1m 9s ) Guest: Ok thanks, Agent K<br>';
String output = input.replaceAll(
  '(?m)^\\s*\\(\\s*(.+?)\\s*\\)\\s*(.+?:)\\s*\\s*(.+)\\s*$',
  '<strong>$2</strong>.$1 $3'
);
System.debug(output);
```

Result:

```
<strong>Agent K:</strong>.12s Hello Guest, How are you doing today?<br> <br>How Can I help<br>
<strong>Guest:</strong>.18s Hello there! Need access to XYZ<br>
<strong>Agent K:</strong>.53s Granted the access<br>
<strong>Guest:</strong>.1m 9s Ok thanks, Agent K<br>
```

---

There's a ton of regex here, but it's simple. I'll break it down:

- `(` and `)` create "numbered capture groups"
- `(?m)` multiline mode, matches newlines with ^ and $
- `^` Start of a line (in beginning position)
- `$` End of a line (in end position)
- `\\s*` Zero or more spaces (we use this a lot to skip whitespace)
- `\\(` and `\\)`, literal parentheses
- `(.+?)` Match any character sequence, but non-greedy (so, up to the next `)`).
- `(.+?:)` match any sequence ending in `:`.
- `(.+)` match to end of line

And for the replacement string, `$1` refers to the first capture group, `$2` to the second group, etc.

P.S. `<b>` and `<i>` are **strongly** discouraged in modern HTML. You should use `<strong>` for bold emphasis (a keyword or heavy emphasis, a concept that must be understood), and `<i>` *should* now be `<em>` for emphasis.

Comment: Possibly worth noting that `<strong>` should be preferred over `<b>` in most cases.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Fair, semantics are important in HTML, this was more a focus on the technique.

Comment: Absolutely, I figured as much.

Comment: @sfdcfox This is extremely helpful.. Thank you so much for this and especially breaking it down with explanation. It works like a charm!

Comment: @sfdcfox I have one small issue with it. My each message doesn't end with  \n and it ends something like this in actual `( 12s ) Agent K: Test msg <br>( 14s ) Guest: Reply msg <br> some on next line <br>( 18s ) Agent K: New msg`  Hence I believe the last group (.+) that is looking until end of line need a change. Could you please suggest for that too? I tried few things but doesn't work well

Comment: @SaurabhKulkarni $ should also match the end of string, even if it's not a newline. I suppose a quick workaround would be to just add a `\n` to the end of your string.

Comment: Thanks for your response @sfdcfox Unfortunately, the input string is not in my control. I will have to identify the places where sequence is <br>( 14s ) and replace it with <br>\n( 14 s ) and once the replacements are done use the way you have mentioned. Does that sound right to you or is there a better way to do it one shot? Really appreciate your all help on this, mate!

Comment: Also to add more, I don't this $ would help as it is not end of string in my case. The string ends when the whole conversation is ended. The break is at **<br>( 14s )** to identify that there is a new line or different user message is starting

Comment: @SaurabhKulkarni The input isn't in your control, but you're literally writing code for this. You can do whatever you want to do with the input string before replacement. If you want, you could use `<br>` in the regular expression as well. You could even `input.split('<br>')` then do the transformation on each element.